# Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern Azure Function Release Pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have successfully configured `build` pipeline configuration for my `Azure Function` in `Azure DevOps`. Now I am configuring a release pipeline with `Azure App Service Deploy` task and I am always getting an error as "`Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern: d:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip. Please restrain the search pattern.`"

[image]

Anyone faced this issue? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure out the issue. The reason behind this is, that your solution has many projects in it and each projects will be having its own zip folder in the artifacts, so to fix this we should specify our Azure Function Project in the Package section of our pipeline task.

Click on the Azure App service Deploy task and the go to the Package or Folder section and then click on the three dots.

[image]

Now you should have an option to select the right zip file.

[image]

Now Create the release again and you should see that the release is successful.

[image]

Hope it helps.